# Property named "type" on embedded records with RESTSerializer in Ember Data - Error no model was found

Tags: rest, serialization, ember.js, ember-data

I use Ember Data 1.13.4.

I have a model with some embedded records, let's say they look like this:

```
var Partner = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr(),
  addresses: DS.hasMany('address', { async: false } ),
});

var Address = DS.Model.extend({
  type: DS.attr(),
  zip: DS.attr(),
  city: DS.attr(),
  street: DS.attr()
});
```

The API sends back the `Address` records embedded in the `Partner` records. Example response:

```
{
  "partners": [
    {
      "id": 47,
      "name": "Johnny",
      "addresses": [
        {
          "id": 7,
          "type": "MAIN",
          "zip": "1234",
          "city": "City-X",
          "street": "6. Nowhere"
        }
      ],
    },
  ]
}
```

The problem is that `type` on the `Address` model is just a normal property, but Ember Data wants it to be the type of the embedded model, and I get this assertion message:

```
Error: No model was found for 'MAIN'
```

Where `'MAIN'` is the content of the `type` property.

I can't change how the API sends back data, I need to adapt to it.

How do I do this?

Edit: Important detail which I forgot to include the first time.
The API has a `/partners/search` endpoint, which I access with a direct ajax request, then I (supposedly) need to call `this.store.pushMany('partner', this.store.normalize('partner', response.partners));` And this is when the `No model was found for 'MAIN'` is raised.

Answer (score 0):

Your `{ partners: { addresses: [ ... ] } }` is returning an embedded data, but because you are providing an object with `id` and `type` ember-data is understanding that the api returns an polymorphic association. And trying to find a model called `MAIN`, but since it does't exist `Error: No model was found for 'MAIN'` is raised.

In order to tell ember-data that your relationship is embedded you need to override the `PartnerSerializer` and include the [DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin.html).

```
App.ApplicationAdapter= DS.RESTAdapter;
App.ApplicationSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer;
App.PartnerSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend(DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin, {
  attrs: {
    addresses: { embedded: 'always' }
  }
})
```

A live demo of this sample running http://emberjs.jsbin.com/nufofehota/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: That's the solution that I also found. However I forgot to include a very important detail: The API has a `/partners/search` endpoint, which I access with a direct ajax request, then I (supposedly) need to call `this.store.pushMany('partner', this.store.normalize('partner', response.partners));` And this is when the `No model was found for 'MAIN'` is raised.